# How do I use a variable in CAML query to send approriate email

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query, splistitem

I have created two list. One is "Storage" the other is "Approvers"

I am able to retrieve all values in the column 'System' in the "Storage" list by iterating through the column list, like so and placing into a global var.

```
        using (SPSite siteCol = new SPSite("http://dev.portal.net/it/dev"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = siteCol.OpenWeb())                                                  
            {
                //Get Storage list 
                SPList list = web.Lists["Storage"];

                //Iterate through the items in the list
                foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
                {
                    //pick out your information needed                                              
                    GlobalWorkflowVar.var = item["System"].ToString();                        
                }
```

Next, I get the "Approvers" list and query that list to retrieve the results.

```
                using (SPSite siteCol2 = new SPSite("http://dev.portal.net/it/dev"))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web2 = siteCol2.OpenWeb())
                    {

                        SPList groupList = web2.Lists["Approvers"];

                        //Write SPQuery/CAML query
                        SPQuery myquery = new SPQuery();
                        myquery.Query =
                            //"<Query>" +
                            "<Where>" +
                                    "<Contains>" +
                                        "<FieldRef Name='Group' />" + "<Value Type='Text'>PO</Value>" +
                                    "</Contains>" +
                            "</Where>";
```

I need to use the global variable so when the variable and query parameters are met, I can send out an email to the appropriate SharePoint Group I defined in the "Approver" list. How would I need to place the variable in the CAML query to retrieve the correct list items. The 'System' column within the "Approver" list has similar values to the 'System' column in the "Storage" list where I am getting the global var.

I.E

"Storage" List - 'System' column - **Email (value)**

"Approver" List - 'System' column - **Email (value)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myquery.Query =
    "<Where>" +
        "<And>" +
            "<Contains>" +
                "<FieldRef Name='Group' />" +
                "<Value Type='Text'>PO</Value>" +
            "</Contains>" +
            "<Eq>" +
                "<FieldRef Name='System' />" +
                "<Value Type='Text'>" + GlobalWorkflowVar.var.ToString() + "</Value>" +
            "</Eq>" +
        "</And>" +
    "</Where>";
```

I think this is what you are asking? The type for the value of the "System" FieldRef may be off depending on how your list is set up.

To send the email, you can use the `SPUtility.SendEmail()` method.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.sendemail.aspx

This may also help: http://davesquared.net/2007/07/sending-email-to-group-with-sharepoint.html

Comment: Okay, I get what you are saying. Is there a way to get the "currentitem" that the workflow instance is running on? By doing this, I can set the variable to that one item to query off of. I was able to retrieve one item only by using the ID, but you have to know the ID before running the WF

Comment: In my Approver list. I have three columns which are: System, Group, and Approver which has the (Sharepoint Group) I want the email to be routed to. This is in a state machine WF task email, so I'm wondering if the createTask_TaskProperties.AssignedTo property where you send it to the group will be different.

Comment: To get the base item, try `OnWorkflowActivated.WorkflowProperties.Item` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowactions.onworkflowactivated.workflowproperties http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowactivationproperties_members.aspx

Comment: Will do. Using this will kickoff the WF to the last item added? SO, I can get rid of this dreaded foreach statement then....lol

Comment: Actually, I was able to retrieve the value using the Query you provided after checking the XML. Now, I just have to make sure it goes to the SharePoint Group selected in my list.

Comment: Sweet, glad I could help. I've never emailed directly to a group personally, but I would assume you would have to retrieve the email address for each `User` in `SPGroup.Users`.

Comment: Okay. I know how to email a group. Just have to reference in the AssigenTo property by setting it equal to = "Sharepoint Group Name". This will be a little different though

Comment: If I have retrieved the item and all its content in the XML? Is there a way to send an email to the group I assigned it to in my list?

Comment: Yeah, first you need to get the group as an `SPGroup`, which you can get from the `SPWeb.Groups` property. Then you need to iterate through each `User` in `SPGroup.Users` and retrieve their email addresses via the `User.Email` property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538244.aspx

Comment: `SPUtility.SendEmail()` can take it from there.

Comment: must be task email..not regular email. I'm using task emails to use the Outlook task capabilities to streamline the process workflow process

Comment: Try this property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroup.distributiongroupemail.aspx I know there is a known bug with SPD workflows sending emails to multiple recipients, but I don't think that applies to this, since this is a distribution list address and not a semi-colon delimited collection.

Comment: oh okay, gotcha